# How to set fonts in a webpage that are not on Google fonts or Font Squirrel?

Tags: html, css

How do I use fonts such as Agency FB, Berlin Sans, Century Gothic etc. in my webpage which, when searched on Google fonts redirect to other sites like

https://store.typenetwork.com/foundry/fontbureau/fonts/agency-fb?src=GoogleFonts
https://www.fonts.com/font/monotype/century-gothic/regular

and if uploaded to Font Squirrel, display the following message

'Font Bureau has requested that their font Agency FB Regular be blacklisted by the Generator. You will not be able to convert this font.'

I have tried the following codes (which worked with fonts which are not of this type)

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'airstrike';
    src: url('fonts/airstrike-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('fonts/airstrike-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Please experts, help me out with this basic (but detrimental to the design of my webpage) problem as this is one of the last ones remaining in my webpage.

Comment: In case the font is commercial, than you gotta buy a licence for web usage. That regular font for a life time is `$2,000`

Comment: @skobaljic What can you say about the fonts I mentioned? Will I be able to use them? If no, then what alternatives would you suggest?

Comment: Try to find [alternatives](https://www.whatfontis.com/Agency-FB-Regular-fontbureau.similar), maybe some of them are free for web.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The side helped me find alternative font which I could use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. I downloaded similar fonts of copyrighted originals from https://www.whatfontis.com/ took the .ttf file and uploaded it to https://www.fontsquirrel.com/ where it got converted into two files of .woff and .woff2 extensions and a sample stylesheet was provided. I just copied the code in my .css file and modified it accordingly. Here is the code i used

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'agency';
    src: url('fonts/agency-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('fonts/agency-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: `woff` is probably enough, glad it helped.